# Is there something like Mandatory template argument that is deduced from other template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have a template which takes 3 template parameter.
I want the third template parameter to be taken by some another template say "CHECK" that may return any integer in  case  as CHECK fails else "1". In case of "1" class X is specialized. 
As shown in following code.
How can I achieved it, i.e. how can I force default template argument to be always used(objective is to make it mandatory not default).If such design is required what should be done?
In short "I want prevent users from supplying that third parameter".

```
   template<typename T, typename D , int = CHECK<T, D>::IS_TRUE >
class X
{
    public :
    X()
    {
        using namespace std;
        cout << "Inside General Implementation " << endl;
    }
};
template<typename T, typename D>
class X<T, D, 1>
{
    public :
    X()
    {
        using namespace std;
        cout << "Inside SPECIAL Implementation " << endl;
    }
    //Specialized Implementaion
};
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) try
{
    X<MyWiget, YourWiget > xObj ; //CHECK  used desired behaviour
    X<MyWiget, YourWiget, 1 > xObj ; //CHECK not used specialized behaviour 
    X<MyWiget, YourWiget, 2 > xObj ; //CHECK not used i.e. default template argument not used
}
catch(...)
{
    //should not land here
    using namespace std;
    cout << " Problems in exception handling in  code";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want prevent users from supplying that third parameter.

Rename your class `X` to `X_impl` and supply a new `X`, with less parameters:

```
template<typename T, typename D, int Int >
class X_impl;


template<typename T, typename D >
class X : public X_impl< T, D, CHECK<T, D>::IS_TRUE > {};
```

Comment: template<typename T, typename D, CHECK<T, D>::IS_TRUE > is not allowed in C++? {see difference int = CHECK<T, D>::IS_TRUE}.Also decoupling implementation then user can directly use implementation that I do not want. Can a template class can have nested template class?

Comment: Can a template class can have nested template class?

Comment: @Sudhendu: Yes, it is (it just wasn't necessary) and yes, it can. But I guess I don't really understand your problem. And judging by the steady stream of answers to your question coming in, I might not be the only one.

Comment: You already solved my problem :).You correctly got my problem that "IIUC, you want prevent users from supplying that third parameter".That is what I was looking for. Thanks "SBI"